# Flutter Storage Permission - ask after every reboot

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions

I have a little problem.
In my Flutter app I use the package permission handler, I query all permissions in the main that I need for the app, like location, systemAlertWindow, camera and so on. When installing the app all permissions are requested and confirmed, but after a reboot the system requests again the manageExternalStorage permission and this after every reboot.
Does anyone know what is causing this?
App runs on Android 12 (API33).
Thanks in advance.

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

main.dart

```
  if (await Permission.storage.status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status !=
      PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  }
  if (await Permission.systemAlertWindow.status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await Permission.systemAlertWindow.request();
  }
  if (await Permission.location.status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await Permission.location.request();
  }
```

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is no normal uses-permission. You cannot request it at runtime like for example WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and so. I wonder what the user sees if you request it that way.

Comment: I know, it also opens the settings and the switch must be pressed, is the same as with systemAlertWindow, however, it does not save the selection as it seems

Comment: Try other devices too.

Comment: already tried, the funny thing is that with some it works and with some the question comes again